# Retrieving Values of Datagrid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid that is bound to a datasource and uses dropdown columns.

```
<DataGrid Name="SFGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Records, 
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="39,33,0,26" 
          SelectionChanged="SFGrid1_SelectionChanged" 
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Width="1067" RowEditEnding="SFGrid1_RowEditEnding" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Cambria">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" CanUserSort="True"  >
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>  
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

My RowEditEnding looks like this

```
public void SFGrid1_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
     var person = e.Row.Item as Person;

     MessageBox.Show("updated Record:" + person.id);
}
```

My problem is that when I move from one cell to the other, RowEditEnding doesnt always trigger. It seems almost if I have to double click on another cell and it usually takes a few times before it shows the new data. I would either like to manually trigger it , like from a button, or at least have it trigger right when I click into a new row...

Answer (score 0):

[DataGrid.SelectedCellsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcellschanged.aspx) would be a great alternative to RowEditEnding.

```
<DataGrid Name="SFGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Records, 
      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="39,33,0,26" 
      SelectionChanged="SFGrid1_SelectionChanged" 
      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Width="1067" SelectedCellsChanged ="SFGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Cambria">
```

Firing the event by pressing a button seems to be impossible (to me) because you are using the provided `DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs` which would be null if you call this function by hand.

Comment: Thank you. When I use selected changed, I still cannot get the edited value, I only can get the original. I am using SFGrid1.CurrentItem.

Comment: Well, there are quite some events you could test. SelectionChanged may be what you are looking for. However, using something like the OnKeyDown event may also be good for archiving this, although using it could really affect your performance in a negative way.